# For a custom library, how can I make dependancies invisible to the host application?

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a custom javascript library that utilizes a third party library like JQuery, RequireJS, etc.  In my particular case it is Dojo.

All the user has to do to use my library is add a script tag like most other libraries.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Host Application</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>Host Application</div>
    <script src="~/Scripts/myLibrary/myLibrary.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Inside my library when it first loads I was thinking to load the third party dependency (Dojo) dynamically as described in these links

http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/loadjavascriptcss.shtml
https://www.sitepoint.com/dynamically-load-jquery-library-javascript/

```
function loadjscssfile(filename, filetype){
    if (filetype=="js"){ //if filename is a external JavaScript file
        var fileref=document.createElement('script')
        fileref.setAttribute("type","text/javascript")
        fileref.setAttribute("src", filename)
    }
    else if (filetype=="css"){ //if filename is an external CSS file
        var fileref=document.createElement("link")
        fileref.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet")
        fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/css")
        fileref.setAttribute("href", filename)
    }
    if (typeof fileref!="undefined")
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref)
}
```

However, since a user may not know that my library uses Dojo  I'm concerned about the scenario where they include Dojo in their application. So essentially load two javascript files, one for Dojo.js, and another for myLibrary.js

```
...
<script src="~/Scripts/myLibrary/myLibrary.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/dojo-release-1.10.6/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
...
```

Furthermore I don't really want the user to be able to call and use the dependencies, they shouldn't be able to use Dojo in the host application just because it was loaded in my library.

Is it possible to isolate my custom library dependencies from the host, so they don't interfere with similar libraries the host may also be loading

EDIT: (also preventing host from accidentally using the dependencies directly - if that's even possible. For example by calling a method that exists on both versions but somehow the version bundled with my library gets executed instead of the intended version)?

Comment: If you are already using `requirejs`, it should be able to do what you are looking for. There are other options like `webpack`, `rollup`, `browserify`

Comment: @DJ. is this something the host application is required to use?

Comment: What would you achieve by preventing them from using the dependency you loaded? Assuming that you're not making changes to the dependency itself, what's the point? Specifically, why bother with possible double loading of a library if you're not actually preventing anything anyway, since anybody can just load the dependency themselves?

Comment: @Roope I see what you mean but my main goal would really be to avoid conflict, in case they decided to included the dependency without knowing its bundled in my library.  Then the conflict would be calling a method that existed on both, but the bundled version got called instead of the one they included.

Comment: I see what you're thinking, but I will still point out that dependencies are a part of normal life for any developer, and the best practice is merely to inform them that you have a dependency and let them worry about fulfilling all the dependencies they have. Note that if the users need Dojo for anything else, you are _forcing_ them to add an extra 165kB or so to the page load, which could have easily been avoided by just letting them load the dependency themselves. But do as you will.

Answer (score 1):

The current popular approach is to *bundle* your dependencies along with your library, producing a single minified javascript file that contains all the necessary parts.

Use a tool like [`webpack`](https://webpack.github.io/) (my recommendation) or [`browserify`](http://browserify.org/) to process all your JS files and the necessary dependencies and create the single bundle.

This imposes no requirements to the user of your bundle. He only needs the single `<script>` tag.

There's abundant documentation and tutorials for both tools. Spend some time googling and learning. It's good to know how to use them.